# ActivityThread error

Tags: android, compiler-errors

Every time I compile my android code to my phone (not an emulator), I always get this kind of code before the app begins to start. (It's just a warning,  the app runs perfectly)

```
09-09 22:13:04.785 26459-26459/com.adrastel.niviel W/ActivityThread: Application com.adrastel.niviel can be debugged on port 8100...
09-09 22:13:07.355 26459-26459/com.adrastel.niviel W/art: Failed to find OatDexFile for DexFile /data/data/com.adrastel.niviel/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_8-classes.dex ( canonical path /data/data/com.adrastel.niviel/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_8-classes.dex) with checksum 0x2dd48748 in OatFile /data/data/com.adrastel.niviel/cache/slice-slice_8-classes.dex
09-09 22:13:08.250 26459-26459/com.adrastel.niviel W/art: Failed to find OatDexFile for DexFile /data/data/com.adrastel.niviel/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_7-classes.dex ( canonical path /data/data/com.adrastel.niviel/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_7-classes.dex) with checksum 0x5a6c56b9 in OatFile /data/data/com.adrastel.niviel/cache/slice-slice_7-classes.dex
09-09 22:13:09.560 26459-26459/com.adrastel.niviel W/art: Failed to find OatDexFile for DexFile /data/data/com.adrastel.niviel/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_3-classes.dex ( canonical path /data/data/com.adrastel.niviel/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_3-classes.dex) with checksum 0xb4a18bff in OatFile /data/data/com.adrastel.niviel/cache/slice-slice_3-classes.dex
09-09 22:13:10.950 26459-26459/com.adrastel.niviel W/art: Failed to find OatDexFile for DexFile /data/data/com.adrastel.niviel/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_2-classes.dex ( canonical path /data/data/com.adrastel.niviel/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_2-classes.dex) with checksum 0x667d4b9b in OatFile /data/data/com.adrastel.niviel/cache/slice-slice_2-classes.dex
09-09 22:13:12.065 26459-26459/com.adrastel.niviel W/art: Failed to find OatDexFile for DexFile /data/data/com.adrastel.niviel/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_1-classes.dex ( canonical path /data/data/com.adrastel.niviel/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_1-classes.dex) with checksum 0x1672e1ac in OatFile /data/data/com.adrastel.niviel/cache/slice-slice_1-classes.dex
09-09 22:13:12.905 26459-26459/com.adrastel.niviel W/art: Failed to find OatDexFile for DexFile /data/data/com.adrastel.niviel/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_0-classes.dex ( canonical path /data/data/com.adrastel.niviel/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_0-classes.dex) with checksum 0x2204c222 in OatFile /data/data/com.adrastel.niviel/cache/slice-slice_0-classes.dex
```

Do you know how to solve that?

Cheers

Comment: This is side effect ow work app or no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like an issue with Instant Run.
The instant run feature of Android Studio lets you preview quick code changes on your phone without having to recompile the whole app package. You can turn that feature off, compiling and testing the app still works. (The feature is still a little bugged, so I personally prefer to disable it)

To turn it off, go to File -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Instant Run and uncheck "Enable Instant Run"